# Wait message while Linux shell script in execution

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

In my shell script which takes 3-4 minutes for output. I want to show some waiting message till that time like `wait for output....`

Comment: `echo "wait for output..."; <script>`

Comment: You could start a script/function in the background, which is printing a dot every x seconds. And kill that background process after the long running part has finished. There is no command for doing `stop process; do somethingelse; continue the process`.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/, and it should better be asked over at https://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -n "Wait for output.."
script > outputfile &
pid=$!
while ps $pid > /dev/null 2>/dev/null ; do
    echo -n .
    sleep 10
done
echo .
echo "And here is that output you've been waiting for:"
cat outputfile
```

Comment: Thanks Lim ... so do I need put above in my script?
I am currently running my script like 
sh /var/opt/mediation/send_manually/loading.sh